# Echo uptime in linux

Tags: linux, echo, uptime

I need to determine the number of users on the system, and if the value, is above or equal to a user count variable set in the script, print out how long the system has been up and what the system load is. How do I add this into my echo? Here in my code

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Syswatch       Shows a variety of different task based on my Linux System
#
# description:   This script will first check the percentage of the filesystem
#                being used. If the percentage is above ___, the root user will
#                be emailed. There will be 4 things echoed in this script. The
#                first thing being the amount of free/total memory being used,
#                second the amount of free/total swap space being used, the
#                third is the user count, and the last thing is the amount
#                of time that the system has been up for and the system load.

#Prints amount of Free/Total Memory and Swap

free -t -m | grep "Total" | awk '{ print "Free/Total Memory : "$4"/"$2"  MB";}'
free -t -m | grep "Swap" | awk '{ print "Free/Total Swap : "$4"/"$2" MB";}'

#Displays the user count for the system

printf "User count is at %d\n" $(who | wc -l)

count=$(who | wc -l)
if [ $count -eq 2 ]
then
  echo "The system has been up for _______  with a system load of average: __"
fi

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`uptime` provides the info your looking for, so you could just call it instead of `echo`:

```
> uptime
 23:40pm  up 13 days  8:09,  6 users,  load average: 1.28, 1.25, 1.23
```

If the format is not satisfactory you could replace the `echo` statement with something like:

```
uptime | sed 's/.*up/The system has been up for/' | sed 's/,.*load/ with a system load/'
```

Or if you really want to use `echo` you could parse the `uptime` output to get the values you want (like you do for `$count`) and use them in the echo statement.

Side notes:

- you're already getting the user count once you could re-arrange the
  code to not call it again:

> ```
> count=$(who | wc -l)
> printf "User count is at %d\n" $count
> ```

- the 'greater or equal' operator is `-ge` not `-eq`:

> if [ $count -ge 2 ]